# Check series convergence using Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Kinda stuck in here too, some kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

Using Taylor expansion check if series :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n}(\arctan{(n+1)} - \arctan{n})$$
converges.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to express $\arctan(n + 1) - \arctan n$ in terms of $n$, and see what happens if you expand that.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**
We have $\arctan x+\arctan\frac{1}{x}=\pi/2,\,\forall x>0$ so 
$$\sqrt{n}(\arctan{(n+1)} - \arctan{n})=\sqrt{n}(\arctan\frac{1}{n}-\arctan\frac{1}{n+1})\sim\frac{1}{n^{3/2}},$$
hence we can conclude the convergence of the series by comparaison with the Riemann series.

Answer (score 3):

Before we apply Taylor series, we will manipulate a bit. Note that
$$\tan\left(\arctan(n+1)-\arctan n\right)=\frac{1}{1+n(n+1)}.$$
Here we have used the formula for $\tan(u-v)$.

Thus $\arctan(n+1)-\arctan n=\arctan\left(\frac{1}{1+n(n+1)}\right)$.

Now the power series for $\arctan x$ will do the job. For the range we are interested in, it is an alternating series. In particular, we conclude that our difference of arctan's is less than $\frac{1}{1+n(n+1)}$, which is less than $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: clever trick with $\tan(u+v)$, haven't seen this before.

Comment: Detail: since $\tan x=\tan y$ is not equivalent to $x=y$, you need a little argument to conclude that $\arctan (n+1)-\arctan n=\arctan(bla)$. You need to invoke that $\arctan (n+1)-\arctan n$ belongs to $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. I think...

Comment: Sure. But $\arctan m$ for large $m$ is close to $\pi/2$ but to the left of it, so is clear we are working in a corner of $(0,\pi/2)$ close to $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that the Taylor series of $\arctan(x+1)-\arctan(x)$ at $x=\infty$ is

$$ \frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^5}+O \left( \frac{1}{x^6} \right)$$

$$ \implies \arctan(n+1)-\arctan(n) \sim \frac {1}{n^2},\quad n\to \infty $$